# Interior of a convex cone and Carathéodory theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

Let $X$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, $S\subseteq X\times\mathbb R$ and $$K=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_ix_i:k\in\mathbb N,x_i\in S,\lambda_i\ge0\right\}.$$

In a lecture note, where the case $X=\mathbb R^d$ was discussed, I've seen the claim that if $(0,1)$ is an interior point of $S$, then $$(0,1)=\sum_{i=1}^{d+1}\lambda_ix_i$$ for some linearly indepednent $x_1,\ldots,x_{d+1}\in S$ and $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{k+1}\ge 0$.

> **Question 1**: How can we show this? And, most importantly, can we obtain a similar conclusion in the case of a general Banach or Hilbert space?
>
> **Question 2**: Moreover, it is claimed that if $(0,1)$ is not an interior point of $S$, then there is a nonzero $w\in X\times\mathbb R$ such that $\langle w,z\rangle\le0$ for all $z\in S$ and $w_2\ge0$. We clearly want to assume that $X$ is a Hilbert space here, but even when $X=\mathbb R^d$, I don't get how this result follows.

I guess the case $X=\mathbb R^d$ is related to the Carathéodory theorem; though I don't know if the claim does actually from it. However, I'm mostly interested in the case of an infinite-dimensional Banach or Hilbert space.

*EDIT*: Maybe we can show that for an interior point of $K$, every $\lambda_i$ must be positive?

Comment: The set $C \subseteq X \times R$ does not seem to be used anywhere? I presume $S$ is any subset of $X$, is this right? And what is $w_2$?

Comment: Further, if $X = \mathbb{R}^d$, then there can be at most $d$ linearly independent elements in any subset of $X$. Are you sure of your assertions?

Comment: @joy Sorry, $C=S$.

Comment: @joy I'm sure that I read that, but I'm not 100% sure if the claim is correct. However, note that $S$ is a subset of $X\times\mathbb R$ and hence, if $X=\mathbb R^d$, then $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^{d+1}$.

Comment: Is there a requirement that $x_1, \ldots, x_{d+1} \in S$? Or, are they any linearly independent elements?

Comment: @joy Yes, the claim is that they belong to $S$. (I'm sorry, I've noticed that I didn't wrote that before.)

Comment: @joy Please note that I've changed the definition from the convex hull to a cone.

Comment: What is $w_2$ in Question 2?

Comment: @joy The second component of $w$, which is an element of the product space $X\times\mathbb R$. So, it is the $\mathbb R$-component. (And $w_1$ is the $X$-component.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: This holds in arbitrary Banach spaces. Let $y \in K$ be given. Thus, $y$ can be written in the form
$$
y = \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i x_i$$
with $\lambda_i > 0$ and $x_i \in S$. W.l.o.g. we assume that $k$ is as small as possible.
If the vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ would not be linearly independent, we have
$$
0 = \sum_{i = 1}^k \alpha_i x_i$$
for some nonzero $\alpha \in \mathbb R^k$. But then we can choose an appropriate $t \in \mathbb R$ such that
$$
y = \sum_{k=1}^k (\lambda_i + t \alpha_i) x_i,
$$
$\lambda_i + t \alpha_i \ge 0$ for all $i$ and $\lambda_j + t \alpha_j = 0$ for at least one $j$. Thus, we can remove all vanishing terms from the sum and we get a representation of $y$ with fewer than $k$ vectors, which is not possible. Hence, $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ are linearly independent.

[Note that $y$ does not need to be an interior point.]

Q2: This fails in infinite dimensional inner product spaces. Indeed, if $S$ is a dense, proper subspace of $X \times \mathbb R$, then $K = S$, the interior of $S$ is empty and $\langle w,z\rangle \le 0$ for all $z \in S$ implies $w = 0$.

Q2 in $X = \mathbb R^d$: Suppose that $y := (0,1)$ is not an interior point of $K$(!). In case that the interior of $K$ is empty $K$ is contained in a proper subspace and we can take a $w$ which is orthogonal to this subspace (maybe we have to multiply by $-1$ to achieve $w_2 \ge 0$).

In case that the interior of $K$ is nonempty, we can use a separation theorem to separate the interior of $K$ and $(0,1)$. Thus, we obtain a non-zero $w$ and some $c$ with
$$
\langle (0,1),w\rangle \ge c \ge \langle z,w\rangle
$$
for all $z \in K$. Since $K$ is a cone we get $c = 0$ and the left-hand side yields $w_2 \ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me how we further see that $\|(0,1)-y\|\ge\nu$ for some $\nu>0$ for all $y\in\partial K$?

Comment: In case $(0,1) \not\in \partial K$ this follows easily since $\partial K$ is closed.

Comment: Regarding Q1: What you've shown is that every element of $K$ has a "minimal representation", but what I don't understand is why in the case $X=\mathbb R^d$ the element $(0,1)$ has a representation with exactly $d+1$ linearly independent vectors (where $d$ is the dimension of $X$).

Comment: Regarding Q2: Couldn't we somehow apply the Hahn-Banach separation theorem :If $K_1$ and $K_2$ are nonempty, disjoint convex subsets of a normed space $Y$ and $K_1$ is open, then there is a $\zeta\in Y'$ and $\gamma\in\mathbb R$ with $$\langle\zeta,x\rangle\gamma\le\langle\zeta,y\rangle$$ for all $x\in K_1$ and $y\in K_2$. Couldn't we apply this (at least if we assume that the interior of the $K$ in the question is nonempty)?

Comment: Is this the kind of separation theorem you've meant? Maybe applied with $K_1=K^\circ$? But what is your $w$? It must be a functional in $(X\times\mathbb R)'$. But how do you define $w_2$ then? And shouldn't your relation only hold for all $z\in K^\circ$?

Comment: Addendum to $(1)$: It is claimed that the fact that $(0,1)$ is in the interior implies that all $\lambda_i$ are $>0$. However, I don't see why this is true. There is clearly always a minimal representation (as you've shown) and if one of the $\lambda_i$'s would vanish, the representation wouldn't be minimal. So, I guess this must have something to do with the claim that the representation has exactly $d+1$ terms.

Comment: Q1 with $X = \mathbb R^d$: Any collection of linearly independent vectors has at most $d+1$ elements and you can fill it up (since $K$ has nonempty interior).

Comment: Q2: Yes, a separation argument could be possible (in infinite dimensions) if the interior of $K$ is not empty. $w$ is the vector you get from the separation theorem and $w_2$ is its second component. Finally, I separated (the interior of) $K$ and $(0,1)$, so $z \in K$ is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Q1: What do you mean by "fill it up" and why is it possible, when $K$ as nonempty interior? Q2: I get that, but why doesn't your relation not only for all $z\in K^\circ$?

Comment: Q1: You add linearly independent vectors until you have $d+1$ many. Q2: By density (and continuity) it holds for all $z \in K$ iff it holds for all $z \in K^\circ$.